# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when executing blur function on OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, exception, exc-bad-access

can anyone help me with this because i can't seem to figure out whats going on here. I am trying to blur and image with a blur function from OpenCV but i get  EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_i386_GPFTL) when the execution reaches the blur function
here's the code

```
void Efekte::Blur_Or_Smooth(Mat &source, Mat &Destination)
{
namedWindow("Blurred / Smoothed", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
int blurSliderValue = 1;
createTrackbar("Blur", "Blurred / Smoothed", &blurSliderValue, 41);
while (true)
{
    int KernelSize;
    if (blurSliderValue%2 == 0)
        KernelSize = blurSliderValue+1;
    else KernelSize = blurSliderValue;

    blur(source,Destination,Size(KernelSize,KernelSize)); // this generates exception

    imshow("Blurred / Smoothed", Destination);
    int key = waitKey(50);
    if (key == 27)
        break;
}
return;
```

}

Comment: nasal demons if blurSliderValue is odd ..

Comment: sorry had a variable name wrong there; fixed it. anyone know whats causing the error. I work on Xcode